# How to create JUnit test cases for Guava's ArrayListMultiMap class in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, guava

I have to create some JUnit test cases for Guava's **ArrayListMultimap** class, but so far, I'm clueless as to how I should proceed. I have successfully been able to create a normal testing class, **ArrayListMultimapTest** (which I've used to test the methods of the class), in which I added Guava's 15 release JAR file as an external library in the build path. But I've been specifically asked to create JUnit test cases for ArrayListMultimap, and I'm not sure as to how I should proceed. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Do you not know how to make JUnit aware of the class and run it in JUnit? Simply add JUnit to build path, too, and look at the [official documentation](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: I'm new to programming. By the way, the problem I'm getting is, when I try to create a new JUnit test case, it asks me to choose from a project. ArrayListMultimap, which is located in **com.google.common.collect**. Should I create a new project which contains all these files and other dependencies, or is there a better way?

Comment: The existing test is [`com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimapTest`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava-tests/test/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimapTest.java?spec=svn8e7d357e239696a1b7674447a72958027a1ec332&r=8e7d357e239696a1b7674447a72958027a1ec332).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the library is *extensively* tested by Google, you can do this easily yourself, if you want.

1. right-click your project in Eclipse
2. select Properties
3. select Java Build Path
4. click Add Library...
   [image: Java Build Path dialog]
5. Select JUnit, pick JUnit4, confirm
   [image: Add Library dialog]

Now you're basically done and you can write your testcases - simply annotate any `public void someName()` method with the `@Test` annotation. If you won't have a `public static main(String... args)` method in your code, then when you'll try to run the class, Eclipse will automatically run it with JUnit.

```
@Test
public void multimapAcceptsMultipleEqualValuesForOneKey() {
    ListMultimap<String, String> listMultimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    listMultimap.put("aha", "eh");
    listMultimap.put("aha", "eh");
    Assert.assertEquals(2, listMultimap.get("aha").size());
}
```

After that, try to dig into JUnit to learn all the goodness it offers you.

Answer (score 2):

There's already such a test. No idea about maven, but just do

```
git clone https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries
```

Then do everything you need to get in Eclipse running (which needs tons of JARs, but you get them all using maven, add them to the build path), open the file and click "run as junit test". Done.

__

Unless you suspect a specific problem, there's no need to write your own tests for Guava as it gets tested and used heavily. Anyway, even if feel like writing it, you should look at the existing ones first (they're sometimes a bit hard to understand as there's a whole testing framework, which is necessary to test that many classes thoroughly).

---

[git](http://git-scm.com) is a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) free to [download here](http://git-scm.com/downloads). It uses command line, but the only one you need to know is written above. [maven](http://maven.apache.org) is an incomprehensible "software project management and comprehension tool" also [free to download](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and use.

As a programmer, you'll need them (or other such tools). Even more, you'll need to [utfg](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/UTFG) a lot.

Comment: Pardon me, but I'm really new to programming! (Just 3 months old)
Could you please tell me where I should run that command, or point me to a tutorial?

Comment: As  I was 3 month old I new nothing. But seriously, links added and UTFG and feel free to ask (in a new question) if you can't find something. And have fun.

Comment: "No idea about maven"? "maven is an incomprehensible software project management and comprehension tool"? Out of curiosity: what's the alternative?

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: I'm not saying that there's an alternative, just that maven seems to be pretty perverted. I don't know much about it (using it from to time only), but even the simplest things look complicated.

Comment: @maaartinus true. The only thing worse than using Maven is not using it

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: So we can agree that's the second worst thing ever, right?